# Get iPhone contacts phone number type

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am able to get the phone no of any contact from following code

```
NSLog(@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty) ,0));
        NSLog(@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty) ,1));
        NSLog(@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty) ,2));
        NSLog(@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty) ,3));
        NSLog(@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPhoneProperty) ,4));
```

but from above code I does not identify which phone number is related to which one (for ex- mobile, home, main, iPhone etc).

Please suggest how can I identify the type of any number?

Answer (score 7):

Try **ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex**, this will give you the type of the phone number

Answer (score 1):

```
 ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty); 

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
  NSString* phoneLabel = (NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,i)
  NSLog(@"%@",phoneLabel);
}
```